# Function to init listeners

Tags: jquery

I have this which is listening for a toggle switch to be changed and calls some AJAX:

```
   $('#notificationStatusBtn').on('switch-change', function(e, data) {      
        if(data.value == true){         
            $.get("myURL");
        }else{
            $.get("myURL");
        }
    })
```

This works fine but I don't really like the function within an argument style. So I tried to refractor it to:

```
    $(document).ready(initListeners());

    //Intialize button listeners    
    function initListeners(){
        $('#notificationStatusBtn').on('switch-change', setNotificationStatus(e, data));
    }

    function setNotificationStatus(e, data){
        if(data.value == true){         
            $.get("muURL",function(data,status){
                    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
            });
        }else{
            $.get("muURL",function(data,status){
                    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
            });
        }
```

But my reworked code isn't working.

Comment: Instead of `$(document).ready(initListeners());` use `$(initListeners)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your callback is not correct in setNotificationStatus. The callback is a reference to your function and therefore doesn't need the variable e and data.

try removing them so you have:

```
$('#notificationStatusBtn').on('switch-change', setNotificationStatus);
```

Your also making the same mistake on the document ready handler:

```
$(document).ready(initListeners());
```

Becomes:

```
$(document).ready(initListeners);
```

Don't be afraid to use alert statements if debugging, it's occasionally useful as a quick and dirty check. You can move to console.log if you want to keep your debugging info.

HTH

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#notificationStatusBtn').on('switch-change', setNotificationStatus(e, data));
```

You are **calling the function** here, not passing it as an argument. Note the parenthesis.

You could try instead:

```
$('#notificationStatusBtn').on('switch-change', setNotificationStatus);
```

You also have the same problem here:

```
$(document).ready(initListeners());
```

Remember, whenever there are parenthesis after a function name, you are **calling** the function. You can simply treat functions as any other variable, when passing them as an argument.

Here's an example console session, to make it clearer:

```
> function test() { return 4; };
undefined
> test
function test() { return 4; }
> test()
4
```